# Android app to detect incomming IM

Tags: android, video, chat

I am building a small robot that I can drive around outside of bluetooth range -- so I want to send signals via the internet.  The eyes and ears are an old Droid phone (running android 2.2.3).  I can get the phone to talk to a bluetooth module to control the robot (tap the left button, it sends the letter L to the bluetooth, which turns the robot etc etc).  I have got Skype or Tango to both give me video and sound to a pc, so that problem is sorted.  The thing I cannot solve is how to send e.g. the letter L over the internet and for the phone to know what I sent.  I wrote an app that checks the contents of a WebDB every second (it works), but that app stops running when I power up the video chat application.  So the question is...how can I get my old Android phone to know that someone via the internet has sent the letter L via Skype or some other way, and for that to happen while I'm also running a video chat application?  PS...my phone has no number, no carrier, and can't receive sms messages or calls.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I wrote an app that checks the contents of a WebDB every second (it works), **but that app stops running** when I power up the video chat application.

So the answer is simple. Write an Android **Service** that runs on the background and polling the internet. Read about android [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), and you can see a real example in the ApiDemos. Good luck!